# Ableton CV from track amplitude? Control another track's dry / wet?

Tags: ableton-live, ableton

**Rather than a gate's simple pass / nopass, is there a way to monitor the amplitude of a track, and apply that amplitude to another track's amplitude or dry / wet?**

---

An audio stream (track) is split into 2 rack chains:

1. original audio
2. muted copy with frequency band isolated

The muted copy has a gate (#1), which opens when the isolated band passes the threshold

---

> A completely separate track has it's own gate (#2) that monitors (#1), and allows it's own instrument to passthrough based on (#1)'s bandpass threshold

---

Where gate is 0/1, is there any sort of 0-127 range send? How would you control a knob from this CV?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `side chain` setup: The gate (or downward expander) is on one track, but it "listens" to key input for the theshold from another track.

Take a look at this video:

Comment: Nice, seems like you just need an effect that has the Sidechain section. Different from Reason where you can manually wire all the CVs

Comment: @neaumusic Yeah, I know that most of Waves' plugins do. I am not familiar with Abletons build in plugins, but I'd be surprised if there are not support for side chaining in dynamic plugins..

Comment: Bear in mind that some plugins will have a sidechain section, but like older hardware devices, this won't be an external sidechan but an internal (filter/EQ) sidechain.

Answer (score 1):

If Max for live is an option:

The [Max For Live Envelope Follower](https://www.ableton.com/en/packs/max-live-essentials/) may suit your purposes if you wish to track audio amplitude for CV another controller.

> Envelope Follower: a Max for Live device that tracks the changes in
>   volume of an incoming audio signal and uses this information to
>   modulate a mapped parameter.

Alternately a suitably configured CV4Live can also be convinced to do some level of audio frequency tracking back into controller data.
http://skinnerbox.de/cv4live.html

I kept a simple single fixed rate sine oscillator handy and used that to set the top and bottom of the CVcontrol frequency expectations. 
Subsequently reassigning the input if the same control to something of interest afterwards.  Combined with the amplitude tracking of 'Envelope Follower' it covered many cases.

Comment: [Further reading](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_wd8AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=amplitude+based+lfo+ableton&source=bl&ots=GCRb4jBxjQ&sig=J3IptI3KTUAYnn2LZrYABaF9vpk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje2IOQjavSAhVFVyYKHSfkBRkQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=amplitude%20based%20lfo%20ableton&f=false) on Envelope Follower